# How to implement localisation with HapiJs and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, localization, hapi.js

MongoDB return the following data:

```
{
 name: {
  "en": "any name",
  "ar": "اي اسم"
 }
}
```

What can be done, if language chosen is **ar** and want this output:

```
{
 name: "اي اسم"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could have multiple fields like name_en and name_ar but frankly your first approach is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework built in to MongoDB, e.g.

```
db.LocalNames.aggregate([
  {$match: {"name.ar": {$exists: true}}},
  {$project: {"name": "$name.ar"}}
])
```

This will match only documents with an Arabic name and then project *just* that value as `name`

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks for the answer. But I also wanted to know what other options we can consider for the same problem, besides this one?

Comment: I have a problem.
What would I do, if I need to populate the **user** and then choose the **name** if using above method?